# change the height of <div> according to <iframe> inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Can anyone tell me how can I change the height of a  `div` according to `iframe` which is inside the `div`.

Here is what I have done so far:

```js
function url2div(url, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 
       '<iframe style="
                       width:100%;
                       height:100%;" 
                       frameborder="0"  
                       src="' + url + '" />';       
}
```

```css
.table1 { width: 100%;
          display:table;
          text-align:center;
          border-width:1px;
          border-color:black;
          border-style:solid;
        }
```

```html
<div class="table1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tdnav">         
        <a href="#" id="list.php" onclick="url2div(this.id, 'content')">My lists</a>
        <a href="#">Dummy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tdic" id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by floating?

Comment: I mean height of div must be change according to iframe's height.

Comment: do you already try to use clearfix?

Comment: maybe you can refer here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ clearfix make the parent follow the children. something like that. I don't really know if it will work on iframe or not. But it's better to use CSS before use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **url2div** function like below. In this *Code Snippet* example below the iframe not loading, because it loading iframe inside iframe. But in your actual browser it will work. The highlighted ***RED*** was **div** and the ***BLUE*** border was your iframe (it not loading content here, it will work on your browser)

**UPDATE :**
You can change the height of **parent div** after the iFrame was loaded.

1) Add a ***onload*** event to your iFrame *(onload='onMyFrameLoad()')*

2) On ***onMyFrameLoad*** function get the **first div** of your ***list.php*** page

3) Get the height of ***first div*** and assign it to the ***.table1*** div

```js
function url2div(url, target) {
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML =
    "<iframe style='width:100%;height:100%;border-color: blue;' onload='onMyFrameLoad()' src='" + url + "' />";
}

function onMyFrameLoad() {
  // Get height of first div and assign it to the table1 div
  var parentDivHeight = document.getElementById('firstDivId').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementsByClassName('table1')[0].style.height = parentDivHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
.table1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="table1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tdnav">
      <a href="#" id="http://www.google.com/" onclick="url2div(this.id, 'content')">My lists</a>
      <a href="#">Dummy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tdic" id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your javascript above I'm guessing the url is dynamic, therefore I'd suggest the following is executed on window load.
I suck at straight Java, so you'd need to load jquery for my solution to work.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
 var url = document.getElementById("iframe_id").src;

 if(url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com') {
  jQuery('div.youWishToFloat').css({'float':'right'});
 } elseif(url = 'http://www.yourdomain2.com') {
  jQuery('div.youWishToFloat').css({'float':'left'});
 }
}
```

You'll need to assign an ID to your iframe for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for reply but by saying "float", I meant height of div. I think it is about my poor english, sorry. And I edited my question. Sorry again.